# Found authority component in URI: when trying yo open an image

Tags: android, image, uri, illegalargumentexception, authority

In my application i collect some images form the device's gallery as files' names.
I whant to display one of the images when ever application started.
When i use the following code -

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String imageFileName = imagesNamesArrayList.get(rndIndex);
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("file://" + imageFileName);
intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

I get the following error -

```
03-22 18:00:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(12560): FATAL EXCEPTION: MediaFeed
```

`03-22 18:00:18.248: E/AndroidRuntime(12560): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found` `authority component in URI: file://mnt/sdcard/tapjoy/cache/images/placeholder.png`

How it can be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the error because your URI is malformed; it looks like you're missing a forward slash.  The two components of the URI are `file://` and the path `/mnt/sdcard/tapjoy/cache/images/placeholder.png` so you should end up with:

`file:///mnt/sdcard/tapjoy/cache/images/placeholder.png`